# How to Convert an Array into an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a circle from a radius and x,y coordinate. I have it all done except the array is not the correct format for my use.
I get:

```
[
    "X_PROPS:40,Y_PROPS:0",
    "X_PROPS:39.99390780625565,Y_PROPS:0.6980962574913405",
    "X_PROPS:39.97563308076383,Y_PROPS:1.3959798681000388",
    "X_PROPS:39.94518139018295,Y_PROPS:2.093438249717753"
]
```

but I need:

```
[
    {X_PROPS:40,Y_PROPS:0},
    {X_PROPS:39.99390780625565,Y_PROPS:0.6980962574913405},
    {X_PROPS:39.97563308076383,Y_PROPS:1.3959798681000388},
    {X_PROPS:39.94518139018295,Y_PROPS:2.093438249717753}
]
```

I tried this:

```
function spec(radius, steps, centerX, centerY){
  var xValues = [centerX];
  var yValues = [centerY];
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    xValues[i] = (centerX + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / steps));
    yValues[i] = (centerY + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / steps));

    result.push('X_PROPS:'+ xValues[i]+','+'Y_PROPS:'+ yValues[i]);
  }

  return result;

}
console.log(spec(40,360,0,0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression `'X_PROPS:'+ xValues[i]+','+'Y_PROPS:'+ yValues[i]` creates a string. Create an object literal instead:

```js
function spec(radius, steps, centerX, centerY) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    result.push({
      X_PROPS: (centerX + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / steps)),
      Y_PROPS: (centerY + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / steps))
    });
  }

  return result;

}
console.log(spec(40, 360, 0, 0))
```